# Javascript - Prototypal inheritance problem and possible general understanding issues

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I started to learn JavaScript, after years of using it without really knowing what's going on, i decided it is time to do something about that. Additionally, I work on a project where JavaScripts can be used to script the Application.

So, enough of all the yada-yada, my problem relates to prototypal inheritance, I *think* I know how it works by now, but there might be issues. The basic Idea is that every object (well, not every object - yeah ;-)) has a prototype where all requests are delegated to if the actual object cannot handle it until the end of the prototype chain has been reached (the prototype of an object can have a prototype too, right?).

In my Application, massive filtering is going to happen and I want to give the users (which are not very technical, It should be as easy as possible.) a way to chain simple filter commands narrowing the result set with each additional call. What do I mean? Smth. like this:

```
zoo.getAnimals().getAnimalsWithFurColor("red").getMammals()
```

`zoo` is always in scope and is an object containing animals and additional properties for the zoo. So, I would have an object like this (lets call it `Container`) to be returned by all method calls in the example:

```
 {
   data: [harryTheElephant, sallyThePenguin, timTheWoodpecker],
   someFilterMethod: function() {
        return new Container(data.filter(function(animal) {
            return animal.someProperty == someValue;
        });
   }
 }
```

So far, so good. But i want the Zoo to be a container too. This is where my real question comes into play: As the zoo has to do some very expensive stuff to retrieve the starting set of animals, i want to lazy-load them. When the zoo gets an `getAnimals()`
 request the data is fetched.

My Idea was to set the prototype of the Zoo to be a Container which obtains its data from the zoo. But I cannot find a way to access the `getAnimals()` method from the zoo from the prototype (the container). I tried it with `this` but the method cannot be found.

Any Ideas how to write code that does what i want to do? Please note that i'm not in  a Browser environment, i embed JavaScript (1.7) in my Application.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not have `getAnimals()` return a `Container`? Does `Zoo` need the other container methods directly?

Comment: Yeah, the `Container` will contain methods to modify the all the contents, so you could do `zoo.getAnimalsByColor("red").setFurColor("blue")` or work directly on the zoo like `zoo.setFurColor("blue")` - OFC, the whole zoo stuff is just an example, in the actual problem it makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense for an object to access the properties of something that (prototypally) inherits from it. E.g., if a `Cat` has a `meow()` method, it would be weird for `Mammal` to reference `meow()`. Similarly, it would be weird for `Container` to reference `getAnimals()`, if `Zoo` is the one deriving from `Container`.

My suggestion, to accomplish your lazy-loading, would be to pass an accessor function that *returns* an array into the `Container` constructor, instead of passing an array directly. This might look something like:

```
function Container(getAnimals) {
    this.someFilterMethod = function () {
        return new Container(function () {
            return getAnimals().filter(function (animal) {
                 return animal.someProperty === someValue;
            });
        });
    };

    this.get = getAnimals;
}

function makeZoo(animals) {
    var zoo = Object.create(new Container(function () { return animals; }));
    zoo.customZooMethod = function () { /* ... */ };

    return zoo;
}

var aZoo = makeZoo([harryTheElephant, sallyThePenguin, timTheWoodpecker]);
var filteredAnimals = aZoo.someFilterMethod().get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects inherit from their internal prototype, not their public prototype.

To implement chaining, just have each method return the instance.

e.g.

```
function Foo(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
} 

Foo.prototype.sayFirstName = function() {
  alert(this.firstName);
  return this;
}

Foo.prototype.sayLastName = function() {
  alert(this.lastName);
  return this;
}

var foo = new Foo('Foo', 'Bar');

foo.sayFirstName().sayLastName();
```

However, chaining isn't a good idea because it makes debugging difficult. If you chain a bunch of commands together and in a single statement or expression and it fails, how do you find out which one failed?

#### Edit

You may want to do something like:

```
// Container constructor
function Container(dataArray) {
  this.data = dataArray;
}

// Filter data and return new container
Container.prototype.getAnimalsWithFurColor = function(color) {
  var filteredArray = [];

  for (var i=0, iLen=this.data.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    // Presuming the items (animals?) in data have a getColor methed 
    if (this.data[i].getColor() == color) {
      filteredArray.push(this.data[i]);
    }
  }
  return new Container(filteredArray);
}
```

Comment: This assumes the OP wants mutable objects, which seems unlikely; he probably wants each filtering call to return a new instance.

Comment: Whatever, the principle is the same.

Comment: I get the basic idea of chaining, as you can see in my example which returns a new container for each filter call. The main problem is the access of object members from the prototype. I see you do that by using `this` in the prototype. It does not seem to work for me... are there any circumstances where it won't work?

Comment: A function's *this* keyword is set by the call, e.g. calling a function as a method of an object will set the function's *this* to the object. You've shown an object and some disjointed code, hard to say what's going on unless you post a "working" example. Obviously the object returned by *getAnimals* has to have a *getAnimalsWithFurColor* method, but you don't show the internal working of those functions which are the ones that need to set *this* appropriately (if that's what you wan to do).